# Refresh TableView Content with UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

Please I would like to refresh the contents of my table but it does not work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Last News";
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    //
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apinae.com/json.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // test refresh
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColormagentaColor];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
    // test refresh

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't set the action for the refresh control. Try this instead:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh..."];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender 
{
    // ... your refresh code
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apinae.com/json.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Well, the call to `-endRefreshing` should be in the delegate method so it stops refreshing when the file is downloaded and refreshed in the table, but you get the idea.

Comment: i have this warning 'Property 'refreshControl' not found on object of type 'ViewController' on line self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

Comment: sorry i don't speak english well

Comment: I understood you fine. You should add `@property (nonatomic,strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;` inside your @interface.

Comment: no warning in my code so on my console there 2013-05-19 20:21:33.315 JSONNews[6219:f803] -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e56010
2013-05-19 20:21:33.317 JSONNews[6219:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e56010'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x14b5022 0xeb5cd6 0x14b6cbd 0x141bed0 0x141bcb2 0x1f606b 0x1f8862 0xa666d 0xa6167 0xa9134 0xad623 0x56d42 0x14b6e42 0x1d86679 0x1d90579 0x1d154f7 0x1d173f6 0x1da4160 0x16e84 0x17767 0x26183 0x26c38 0x1a634 0x139fef5 0x1489195 0x13edff2 0x13ec8da 0x13ebd84 0x13ebc9b 0x16c65 0x18626 0x2b1d 0x2a45 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: This is an unrelated error, and says that you are trying to use a UIView as if it was a UITableView. Is the view controller a UITableViewController ? maybe you should create a sample project using the “Master-Detail Application” template and read the code to see how it works.

Comment: i have re created my project so i have not error but the cell table is empty

Comment: Since this is an unrelated issue, go one step at a time. For example, try to read the JSON file from the Internet and print the results using `NSLog`. If you encounter any issues, post it on a different question.

Comment: it works reading the json file in "viewDidLoad" whereas when I moves in "refresh (UIRefreshControl *) sender" does not work. However, thank you for your help it gives me ideas for refresh